# Rails: activerecord-reputation-system vs Acts As Votable

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have an e-commerce app built with rails, I want to let my users rate a product from 1 to 5 stars when they purchase.

So Im looking for some gem that has this built in, I did some of research and I found the [activerecord-reputation-system](https://github.com/twitter/activerecord-reputation-system) and [Act as votable](https://github.com/ryanto/acts_as_votable) gems, I want to make the best choice so I would like to heard from you what are the advantages or disadvantages to use one or the other

Comment: Any reason why you want to use a gem for such a simple task? This can be done easily without any effort.

Comment: if that were like "without any effort" wouldn't exist gems for that.

Comment: ```class Product; has_many :ratings``` . In a separate table ( ratings ) you have ```product_id``` and rating(integer) 1..5 / 1..10 . Then based on that, you create an average from all the ratings from that product. Like I said, simple. Obviously, I might be wrong and you, indeed, need a gem for that, it only depends on your application and wether or not you want something more than just a 'simple' rating for a product.